# How compare to a constant with WaitOnAddress

Tags: c++, futex

In Linux, futexs have the following signature
`long futex(uint32_t *uaddr, int futex_op, uint32_t val, const struct timespec *timeout)`, so I can say `syscall(SYS_futex, &m_address, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, nullptr);` which will pause the current thread if the value at m_address is 1.

What I want to know is how do I do this in windows.

The signature for `BOOL WaitOnAddress(volatile VOID *Address, PVOID CompareAddress, SIZE_T AddressSize, DWORD dwMilliseconds)`. There's no option for a value. Do I have to make a variable with constant value and pass it to CompareAddress or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

WaitOnAddress is not used as a single call wait instruction, it is generally called in a loop e.g. [Raymond Chen - A helper template function to wait for WaitOnAddress in a loop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180118-00/?p=97825).  Nor will it wake without extra help, whatever code changes the bytes at Address must also call WakeByAddressSingle or WakeByAddressAll to allow any active WaitOnAddress calls to return.